# RowsExceededException when using big number of rows

Tags: java, csv, jxl

I try to create a very large excel file with java jxl, a file of more than 20 gb, the problem is that when I try to make a loop a little bigger to generate more line, I have a error message

```
"jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException: The maximum number of rows permitted on a worksheet been exceeded
  at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.getRowRecord(WritableSheetImpl.java:975)
  at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.addCell(WritableSheetImpl.java:951)
  at test2.Test2.main(Test2.java:66)
```

this is my code

```
try { 
        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("sortie.xls")); 
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Premier classeur", 0); 
        //Crée le format d’une cellule 
        WritableFont arial10font = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 12,WritableFont.BOLD, true, UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE,Colour.BLACK, ScriptStyle.NORMAL_SCRIPT); 
        WritableCellFormat arial10format = new WritableCellFormat(arial10font); 
            //Crée un label à la ligne 0, colonne 0 avec le format spécifique 

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {


                    String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ;
                    String chars2 ="azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn" ;
                    String chars3 ="aqwzsxedcrfvtgbyhnujikolpm" ;
                    String pass = "";
                    String pass2 = "";
                    String pass3 = "";
                    int alava = 6 ;
                    for (int x = 0; x < alava; x++) {
                        int p = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*26);
                        pass +=chars.charAt(p);
                        pass2 +=chars2.charAt(p);
                        pass3 +=chars3.charAt(p);
                    }
                    Label label = new Label(0, i, pass); 
                    Label label2 = new Label(1, i, pass2); 
                    Label label3 = new Label(2, i, pass3); 
                    //Crée un label à la ligne 2, colonne 0 sans style prédéfini 
                    //Label label2 = new Label(0, 2, "Résultat"); 
                    //Ajout des cellules 
                    sheet.addCell(label); 
                    sheet.addCell(label2);
                    sheet.addCell(label3);


        }

            //Ajout d’une cellule ligne 2, colonne 1 
            //Number number = new Number(1, 2, 3.1459); 
            //sheet.addCell(number); 
            //Ajout d’une image ligne 4, colonne 0 
            //Taille de l’image : 6 lignes et 2 colonnes 
            //WritableImage image = new WritableImage(0, 4, 2, 6,new File("Logo-Labo-Sun.png")); 
            //sheet.addImage(image); 
            //Ecriture et fermeture du classeur 
            workbook.write(); 
            workbook.close(); 
            } catch (RowsExceededException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (WriteException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }finally{ 
        System.out.println("Le fichier \"sortie.xls\" à été généré correctement."); 

    } 
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Comment: as the error says, `The maximum number of rows permitted on a worksheet been exceeded` ...

Comment: Is it .xls or .xlsx ? The first one has a limit of 64000 rows I remember

Comment: Why do you want to create a 20 Gb Excel file?!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you seem to have no use for any advanced Excel capability and to only want to generate tabulated data you can open in your spreasheet editor of choice, I think you should consider generating a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

The following code produces similar data to your own without the need for any additional library and I've been able to open the resulting file in Excel simply by double-clicking it from Window's file explorer.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestCSV {

    private static final String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static final String chars2 ="azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn";
    private static final String chars3 ="aqwzsxedcrfvtgbyhnujikolpm";
    private static final int alava = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File("sortie.csv"))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                String pass="", pass2="", pass3="";
                for (int x=0; x < alava; x++) {
                    int p = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*26);
                    pass +=chars.charAt(p);
                    pass2 +=chars2.charAt(p);
                    pass3 +=chars3.charAt(p);
                }
                out.write(String.format("\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\"%n", pass, pass2, pass3));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is exceed the write limit on an XLS file. The limit is 65536 rows. The following code fragment illustrates how to fix

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("file_test.xls")); 
WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test sheet", 0); 

for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
    ...
}
```

PS: To generate a 20 GB file, it is necessary to create several XLS files, when the limit of 65536 rows is reached.